# Display indention of long lines in following lines in vim

Tags: vim, indentation

When I have a long line indented in vim, it wraps at the end of the window automatically (just visually). I'd like to show the indention in the next lines as well. Is it possible?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `:help 'linebreak'`?

Answer (score 2):

**This visually indents lines that have been wrapped:**

```
:set wrap
:let &showbreak='                 '
```

Note, the indent width is fixed; it doesn't try to match the indent of the previous line

**Before**

```
abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc
```

**After**

```
abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc
                abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc
                abc abc abc abc abc abc
```